# read a webpage into a string, modify it, then output it

Tags: php

I've got a template page that's a combination of HTML and PHP. I want to output the whole contents into another page, but I want to modify the contents first dynamically before outputting, including the code.

If I understand correctly `eval()` needs to strip out the PHP words and the opening `<?`.

So far I've got the following:

```
    $str = file_get_contents($template);
    [Create an array of changes to make]

    $str = str_replace($changes,"",$str);

    $changes2 = array();
    $changes2[0] = '?php';
    $str = str_replace($changes2,"?",$str);
    $str = substr($str,3);
    eval("\$str = \"$str\";");  
    echo $str;
```

I originally just opened the contents in an `iframe`, but as I said I need to edit the code within the file first before outputting (and without modifying the original template code).

The only other way I can think of doing it is reading the template into a string, changing what I need to, writing the contents of that string to a temporary file, then reading in the temporary file.

But it feels like that's the long-winded method of doing this.

Does anyone know the right way of doing it?

Comment: For the love of God, don't use `eval()`. If `eval()` is the answer, you asked the wrong question! ;)

Comment: That's fine. I don't mind not using it, I just don't know of another method other than creating a temp file.

Comment: What are the changes you need to make? If it's just DOM manipulation, could this potentially be done using jQuery?

Comment: Are you making a theme kind of template or is this for a structured set of data?  In other words, is every page using this or just one or a few?

Comment: That `eval()` just sets `$str` to the contents of `$str`.

Comment: It's just on one page, I'm trying to import a template based on the users choice in a select menu. so the user selects a template and it reloads the page either including the template or displaying it in an iframe. But I need to replace some php code of that template before displaying it. Can I manipulate the code before putting it in an iframe instead then?

Answer (score 0):

Use **[output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php)**

It allows you to capture (Buffer) output, place it into a variable, do whatever you want, then output again.

If you need your HTML edited after it was processed by PHP, output buffering is the way to go.

Simplest example:

```
<?php

ob_start();

echo "Hello World"; //Even though it was echoed, not getting displayed since buffered

$out = ob_get_clean(); //Get buffer into variable, then delete it, without displaying.
$out = strtolower($out);

var_dump($out); //Now output the new value, will show "hello world".
```

In your case, you'd `include` the relevant file (Rather than `file_get_contents()` it), capture the output, alter the changes, and then echo the fixed output.

Comment: No. It would seem as though your approach is wrong. Dynamically changing PHP code is nearly never the answer, and this doesn't feel like that one in a hundred thousandth case. Would you mind sharing what's your purpose?

Comment: I've said what it's for in the comments for the answer above. It's just for the admin end of a website.

Comment: @jimbeeer: Still not a good approach. If you want to grant edit privileges for PHP files, grant him a user on the server with restricted access, or otherwise give him access via FTP or something.